# UITableViewController keyboard scrolling behavior inconsistent

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, keyboard

I'm running into an issue with the keyboard "pushing" The `UITableViewController` cell up.

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7), a `UITableViewController` class automatically resizes and repositions its table view when there is in-line editing of text fields.

I'm seeing this correct behavior when I initially load my view.  My table cell that contains a `UITextView` properly gets "pushed up."

However, I have a tab bar which allows me to load additional views.  If I click to go back to my original view again, however, the keyboard loads on top of my table cell instead of pushing it up.  This does not trigger `ViewDidLoad()`.

Do I have to do anything specific to reinitialize the UITableViewController, perhaps in `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: The `viewdidload()`gets only called when the view is added to the stack, the `viewDidAppear()` gets always called the view appears.

Comment: @Lovo, that's what was making me wonder if anything special happened in `viewDidLoad()` in relation to this issue.  Maybe that's totally unrelated, though.

Comment: I don't know what you do in the `viewDidLoad()` but you shouldn`t add logic that needs to happen more often